# Why "Error: EINVAL" & "EPRM:Permission denied" Problem causing in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, npm, yarnpkg

When i tried to run `npm create-react-app` and `yean create react-app` command, It returned me an error of `Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Roaming\npm'`

I tried to clear the catch with the `*npm cache clear*` `*npm cache clean --force*` command. But the results are the same as before.

**what causes it and how can I solve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WIN+R to open a small window of operation, and then enter '.' (dot) And click OK, so that you enter the system user directory of your C drive;

After entering the system user directory, you can find the file .npmrc This file, after opening this file, you can see the [see the prefix value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUse0.png)

now change whatever the prefix=xxxx value is. with the given image. And now try again.

This solved my problem.
or lookup this link: https://www.programmersought.com/article/91716179653/